# change mail to keep offline setting to two weeks in outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

Is there any way to change this setting to less than 1 month (e.g. 2 weeks)?
Is there any registry hack for this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set it to 3 days, 1 week or 2 weeks. These settings are stored in the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Cached Mode`:

`SyncWindowSetting` (DWORD): 0, 1, 3, 6, 12, 24, 36, 60 (in months, 0 = all).

`SyncWindowSettingDays` (DWORD): 3, 7, 14.

For example, in order to set the cache window to 2 weeks, you need to set `SyncWindowSetting` to 0 and `SyncWindowSettingDays` to 14.
 More details in [Microsoft KB Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3115009/administrators-set-additional-default-mail-calendar-sync-windows).

Comment: This is actually incorrect. In Outlook 2016 there are two registry keys that are in play here, `syncwindowsetting` and `syncwindowsettingdays`. This [Microsoft link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3115009/administrators-set-additional-default-mail-calendar-sync-windows) goes over it.